# Passing an id of an element to ruby using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a list of items in a table, where each item displays an attribute of a Ruby class called Record. Each item sits in its own row. Each `<tr>` has an `id` that mirrors the name of the attribute, and at any given time one row will have the class `alpha` and one will have the class `beta` — as shown below:

#### Initial code

```
<table>
  <tr id="attribute_1">
    <td><%= @record.attribute_1 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="attribute_2" class="alpha">
    <td><%= @record.attribute_2 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="attribute_3">
    <td><%= @record.attribute_3 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="attribute_4" class="beta">
    <td><%= @record.attribute_4 %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The rows labeled `alpha` and `beta` are changing constantly. I want to be able to determine the id of the table row with these respective classes and pass them to ruby, so that I can (for the purposes of this question) switch them, for example (and yes, I know there are way easier ways to do this without using ruby at all, but just go with it).

The way I'm trying to do this right now utilizes jQuery, which calls a function when a button is pressed.

```
$(function document() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    var alphaId = $(".alpha").attr("id");
    var betaId = $(".beta").attr("id");
    $(".alpha td").html("<%= @record." + betaId + " %>");
    $(".beta td").html("<%= @record." + alphaId + " %>");
  });
});
```

This doesn't work because the ruby fails to compile. Ultimately, the result should look like this:

#### Intended Results

```
<table>
  <tr id="attribute_1">
    <td><%= @record.attribute_1 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="attribute_2" class="alpha">
    <td><%= @record.attribute_4 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="attribute_3">
    <td><%= @record.attribute_3 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="attribute_4" class="beta">
    <td><%= @record.attribute_2 %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Notice the outputs of attribute_2 and attribute_4 are switched. Let me know if you have any alternative approaches to solving this problem! Thanks.

### Edit

Also, it's worth noting that the jQuery sits in the view file *views/records/switch.js.erb* and is executed server-side. For example, the following code works fine:

```
$(function document() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    var alphaId = $(".alpha").attr("id");
    var betaId = $(".beta").attr("id");
    $(".alpha td").html("<%= @record.attribute_4 %>");
    $(".beta td").html("<%= @record.attribute_2 %>");
  });
});
```

and I would go for this, but the number of attributes is enormous and they're constantly changing.

Comment: The interpretation of your edit is wrong: the js isn't executed server-side, it's just ruby parsing the view and putting the right variable at the right place because it's explicitly called.

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically manipulate the call to reflect a jQuery variable?

Comment: you must either create a js variable like I did in my answer, OR using AJAX, OR creating a loop in Ruby which would be executed server-side. The best way to achieve wat you expect remains the first choice = the answer I wrote

Comment: did I answer your question? I saw you removed the comment presenting a first error.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I ended up changing my approach anyway so I didn't end up using it. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it fails to execute:

- ruby is executed server side
- your js would only be executed client-side

=> they can't work together this way.

You should create a js variable and work with it in you js. Something like:

```
var records = <%= @record.to_json%>;
```

And then depending on the json structure:

```
$(".alpha td").html(records[betaId]);
```

Comment: well, it's not what I wrote, notice I put `<%=`